# ESP8266 - PULLUP resistor using Arduino code

Tags: arduino, esp8266

I'm having some trouble with [this ESP8266](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/ESP8266-CH340G-CH340-G-NodeMcu-V3-Lua-Wireless-WIFI-Module-Connector-Development-Board-Based-ESP-12E/32800966224.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.3da24c4diFI6iN), to switch UP, DOWN, OFF [dual relay](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/3V-2-Channel-Relay-Module-3-3V-Optocoupler-Isolation-Module-Relay-Control-Board/32847869020.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.5eb64c4dCk5Jcq), using Arduino code and a physical 3 states switch.

The code defines input GPIOs 12,14 as `INPUT_PULLUP` to avoid cases that from time to time ( say once a day ), I get a phenomena that is typically for not using a pull-up resistor.

What can cause such a thing?
Can it be that GPIO12, GPIO14 does not HAVE a pull-up resistor on-board?

Relevant code (that defines inputs and outputs):

```
void setup() {

        Serial.begin(9600);

        pinMode(switchUpPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
        pinMode(switchDownPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
        pinMode(relayUpPin, OUTPUT);
        pinMode(relayDownPin, OUTPUT);

        digitalWrite(relayUpPin,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(relayDownPin,HIGH);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, GPIO12 and GPIO14 have internal pull-up resistors (see table below). If they are properly setup in software I would suggest looking at the output (relay control circuit). Since you provided no information about the relay or how you control it I can't give a better answer.

[image: ESP8266 pull-up table]

Table from [here](https://bbs.espressif.com/viewtopic.php?t=1079)

Comment: thank you. Dual relay link added to Q, and piece of the code.

Comment: seems no document tell the internal pull-up resistor value.
some blog says it about 40~60 KΩ:
https://rayshobby.net/wordpress/tips-and-tricks-for-using-esp8266/#:~:text=The%20way%20this%20works%20is,about%2040%20to%2060%20Kohm.

Answer (score 2):

The NodeMcu has no pull-up on pins 12 and 14. The esp8266 has internal pull-up and you activate it with pin mode INPUT_PULLUP. Without activated internall pull-up, there is no pull-up for this pns.

Comment: As you can see in my code, it IS initiated with `INPUT_PULLUP` but the behaviour, scarcely, seems it does not have any.

Comment: you say that the internall pullup doesn't help?

Comment: I say that, I had some occurrences that erratic triggering happened ...

Comment: ...while already using internal pull-up. I was not sure how to understand the question. So voltage drops while WiFi consumes too much power?

Comment: you know I have my language limitations :) - Yes, it happened when PULLUP was already defined in code. I'm using a 2A DC adaptor, I doubt if the esp8266 consumes power in that scale.

Comment: esp8266 max 300 mA. but the relays? are they powered from same adapter?

Comment: do you mean - what is relay's power consumption during idle time ? erratic triggering happened not during activation of relay ( if I understand you correctly ).

Comment: then I am out of ideas. try external pull-up